# How to disable ink management when printing duplex

Tags: printer, printing, inkjet-printer, duplex

I own a brother MFC-J6910DW printer. when printing one-sided pages, the colors are great (dark and saturated), but when printing duplex, the colors look faint (specially black, it looks grey-ish and not dark black) after some research I found out that this is common with duplex ink-jets, this is done so ink would dry faster, and to protect the interior of the printer when printing on the other side.

while this is not a bug nor it is specific to brother printers, i would like to bypass/disable this mechanism, I know it's not recommended, but when reading long documents, the dark text is much easier to the eye.

Comment: more on the topic:http://kbsupport.cusa.canon.com/system/selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=1011&PARTITION_ID=1&secureFlag=false&TIMEZONE_OFFSET=&CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=17583